# How to determine file or regular string? AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, gsap

I load strings from a mxl. 
Some of the strings are file paths and some of them are just normal strings.
How I can to determine who is a file and who is a regular string?

Thanks

Comment: I have no experience in AS, but I imagine that you could test if the file exists. If the file doesn't exist, hopefully it's a string. Not perfect, but a start.

Comment: @Dan: Are these relative paths (file.jpg) or absolute paths (http://site.com/file.jpg) or both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regular expression check on each string. [This](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/RegExp.html) page explains usage and some examples of RegExp syntax. What your regular expression includes depends on what your file locations look like, but one thing you can look for is the file type suffix.

And I just found [this tool](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) for constructing and testing regular expressions.

The following regular expression would match any word (substring with no whitespace) ending with a file extension, such as .pdf or .mp3. But it will also recognize .com, .org, etc, so hopefully your strings don't contain website urls.

```
var str:String = inputString; // Each string you want to test.
var regEx:RegExp = /\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\b/; // Note that no quotes are needed.
var matches:Boolean = regEx.test(str); // True for match, false for no match.
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can edit the xml, I would use a `<file>` or `<string>` tag (or attribute) in my xml structure. Then when reading it in you know for sure what it is without having the extra overhead of seeing if a file exists.

If you want to check if a file exists, without using AIR or another 3rd party swf wrapper, you can attempt to load the path using `URLRequest`, `URLLoader` and listening for an

`IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR` (it does not exist)

`Event.COMPLETE` (it has loaded, and does exist) .

As mentioned, the best way would be to edit the xml though.

Comment: nice... you gave me an idea, Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If file paths follow a specific pattern which the other strings don't follow, you can differentiate based on that pattern. For example, if all paths start with `http://`, you can check your strings for existence of `http://`. If there is no such distinction between paths and other strings, you can add an attribute or a child element to your XML tags to indicate which XML elements contain paths. Here's an example:

**XML**

```
<root>
    <string>abc<string>
    <string isPath="true">abc.txt</string>
    <string isPath="false">xyz</string>
</root>
```

**AS3**

```
var xml:XML; // I'm assuming that this variable already contains the XML

var paths:XMLList = xml.string.(@isPath == 'true');
var regularStrings:XMLList = xml.string.(@isPath != 'true');
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I dont want to rely on the XML so I think I will use the first option.